# serverless framework with multiple requirements.txt files

Tags: serverless-framework

I have a python project with structure as below:

```
/project/
    /function-group-1/
         lambda-A.py
         requirements.txt
    /function-group-2/
         lambda-B.py
         lambda-C.py
         requirements.txt
```

Can you have some ways to install packages from requirements.txt, then packaging it as separated layers? I used serverless-python-requirements plugin, but maybe it not help to create multiple layers with multiple requirements.txt files